# How to send image using Mandrill but image name should not rename?

Tags: php, phpmailer, mandrill

Image file attachments in mandrill api working fine. But here,

```
'type' => 'image/jpeg',
'name' => "",     // Here I didn't  know what I am use 
'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($img))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
'name' => basename($img)
```

if you do not want to rename the image.

Hope this helps,